# combining datasets with different number of rows

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes: data1 (12 rows), data2 (12 rows), and data3 (12 rows). I want to combine the 3 into a single dataframe with one column and 48 rows keeping all the values.

```
    data1: 
   [1] "Ank2_S3226"          "Scg2_S556"           "Nefh_S571"          
   [4] "Sgip1_S95"           "Amph_S504"           "Srcin1_S546"        
   [7] "Ank2_S1816"          "Map1b_S1373"         "Asb3_S35"           
  [10] "Scg2_S556"           "Ank2_S1816"          "Mapt_T58" 



    data2:
   [1] "Ank2_ S3229"          "Nefh_ S577"           "Srcin1_ S555"        
   [4] "Ank2_ S1819"          "Map1b_ S1384"         "Ank2_ S1819"         
   [7] "Wdr37_ S24"           "Gmip_ S440"           "Apc_ S"              
  [10] "Nefh_ S679"           "Map1b_ S1384"         "Map1a_ S355"



    data3:
  [1] "Ank2_ S3230"          "Map1a_ S359"          "Crocc_ S501"         
  [4] "Wnk2_ S1754"          "Slc16a1_ S491"        "Srrm2_ S1400"        
  [7] "Map1b_ S1797"         "Ccm2_ S361"           "Camk2a_ T337"        
 [10] "2310035C23Rik_ T/S/Y" "Ank2_ S2583"          "Svop_ S31"
```

I used the `merge()` function `data4<- merge(data1, data2, all=TRUE)` but it gave something like this

```
    x           y
1           Ank2_S3226 Ank2_ S3229
2            Scg2_S556 Ank2_ S3229
3            Nefh_S571 Ank2_ S3229
4            Sgip1_S95 Ank2_ S3229
5            Amph_S504 Ank2_ S3229
6          Srcin1_S546 Ank2_ S3229
7           Ank2_S1816 Ank2_ S3229
8          Map1b_S1373 Ank2_ S3229
9             Asb3_S35 Ank2_ S3229
10           Scg2_S556 Ank2_ S3229
```

Please help

Comment: Your title says _different number of rows_ but you then say they all have 12 rows. ???

Comment: Are you sure those are 3 dataframes, they look like vectors.

Comment: @Edward I gave a short example here. There are 6236, 2311, 610 rows.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes these were vectors and converted them to dataframe using data1<- data.frame(data1)                                                                                                   Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `c`

```
data.frame(y = c(data1, data2, data3))
```